# Making massive numbers of HTTP requests in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, http, http-headers

I'm trying to test a web application, part of this involves making ~10K requests, taking the few <1K that return `200 OK` and going through their data. The webapp is buggy and there are false positives, so each 200 OK needs to be at least triple-checked.

Working in Python I was trying to do this with threading and urllib, but on linux I get thread errors after ~920 threads. (My theory is it's `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` divided by thirty which is eerily accurate, but it's perturbing that each thread would register as 30 threads with the os). In any case, I'm looking for a good solution for this task. I've looked into Twisted, but it seems like I will still be bound by threading.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you adjust your resource limits via http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html?

Comment: just to clarify the task a bit: you whant to open ~10K threads ? i would work with 10 tops each making multiple requests, deal with the output then log it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  was testing whit [apache ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) web server [TORNADO](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) and was unable to go much over 1000 connections per second on my dual core athlon @ 2Ghz . 30% resources took testing tool ab and remaining was for server. I am pretty convinced that most resources are spent by OS and IP-eth layer.

http://amix.dk/blog/post/19581
non blocking servers have better performance than blocking servers since they does not spawn tread for each connection. In theory they can run in single tread.

Comment: This is a really beautiful solution but it's way past my needs. But I see now that the finite-ness of possible connections is probably a more limiting factor than max number of threads. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [asynchronous HTTP requests](http://pythonquirks.blogspot.com/2009/12/asynchronous-http-request.html) (there's sample code at the bottom of the article).

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with [FunkLoad](http://funkload.nuxeo.org/) for scripting bulk transactions with web sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have use the Python bindings for libcurl ([pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/)) in the past for this. Use the multi client feature, which does it asynchronously in C. It's pretty fast.